# How to scrape mobile phone numbers using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape just mobile phones with below formats:

```
+1 NXX-NXX-XXXX

N=digits 2–9, X=digits 0–9

+1 is the country code that includes the US, there are 17 other countries, e.g., Canada, Caribbean Islands.
```

Assume we need to find every numbers that started by 986 and 965 and etc (we have a set of this numbers) as first NXX.

This is my code to get emails:

```
    email = soup(text=re.compile(r'[A-Za-z0-9\.\+_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]*'))

    _emailtokens = str(email).replace("\\t", "").replace("\\n", "").split(' ')

    if len(_emailtokens):
        print([match.group(0) for token in _emailtokens for match in [re.search(r"([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)", str(token.strip()))] if match])
```

But I need to change it to get mobile phones.

Comment: Have you tried changing the regex?

Comment: Dear @Phix, I don't know how can I do that.

Comment: in what text do you try to find numbers ? Maybe there are better methods to get it.

Comment: Dear @furas, my purpose is to find numbers from webpages and their contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have written a **scraper** to store your string of numbers (mobile and non-mobile) in a list (in your case, you are most likely to have split the numbers into a list based on your code), then the following snippet of code (with regex) may help you.

Code

```
import re

#NXX-NXX-XXXX
#NXX 986 or 965
#N=digits 2–9, X=digits 0–9

#here is the regex pattern you need
pattern = r'(?=[2-9]{1}[0-9]{2}-[2-9]{1}[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$)((?P<hello>986.+)|(?P<world>965.+))'

#Note: give your groups (986 and 965) a sensible name, I am using hello and world for demonstration

sent = ['986-233-8901', '965-345-8745', '123-456-7890', '986-134-5987', '1234', '$5@67^73']
#Matched, Matched, None, None, None, None

regexp = re.compile(pattern)

#the matched results
result = [regexp.match(item) for item in sent]
#change to regexp.search() if needed

#a way to retrieve group elements with prefix 986 (group hello)
hello_group = [item.group('hello') for item in result if item is not None]
```

Outputs

```
print(result)
#[<re.Match object; span=(0, 12), match='986-233-8901'>, <re.Match object; span=(0, 12), match='965-345-8745'>, None, None]

print(hello_group)
#['986-233-8901', None]
```

Comment: Dear @QuantStats, very nice code. Now my problem is how to make this sent array from webpages (I mean which type of html tags might be better to use as candidate in our sent list).

Comment: @WilliamJohnson It depends on the structure of the html you are scrapping from. You could avoid making this sent array by calling something like bs.find_all('a', text=re.compile(pattern)) directly for example if it is feasible. I hope it helps.

Comment: Dear @QuantStats, Thank you for your valuable comment, I want to use this approach, but unfortunately the mobile numbers might be find in every tags and I need to check for all li tags and maybe p tags and also links (td div li a p) and etc.

Comment: @WilliamJohnson I think I get what you mean. If you post mind posting your url here, others may be able to help you with writing the scrapper.

Comment: FYI it's __scraper__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scrape__) not scrapper. 'To scrap' means to throw away like rubbish :-(